# How to dispatch an event from ViewNavigatorApplication to another View

Tags: apache-flex, events, mobile

I would like to dispatch an event from the `ViewNavigatorApplication` and to catch it in another view.

```
var terminateEvent:MyEvent = new Event(MyEvent.COMPLETE);
dispatchEvent(terminateEvent);
```

I do not succeed to catch the event in another view

```
this.addEventListenerMyEvent.COMPLETE, terminateExperiment_Handler);
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Events should only be used to communicate up the display hierarchy; not down.

If you want to communicate down you should do so by changing properties or calling methods on your view class.

That said, you can add your listener on the application from your view using [FlexGlobals](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/FlexGlobals.html#topLevelApplication):

```
(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication as ViewNavigatorApplication).addEventListenerMyEvent.COMPLETE, terminateExperiment_Handler);
```

Listening to a 'parent' in this way is usually consider a breach in encapsulation and I wouldn't recommend that approach lightly.